# First-Order Linear Equations

Tags: calculus

I have the equation,

$$\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{2y}{x} = x^2$$

and I have tried solving it using $e^{G(x)}$ but I get the answer $y(x) = x^4$ which isn't correct. I got the integration of $g(x)$ to be $-2ln|x| + C$ which seems to be right but implementing it in the equation didn´t work for me.

I got

$$\frac{dy}{dx} \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{2}{x} \frac{1}{x^2}  y = \frac{1}{x^2}  x^2$$

and then

$$\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg(\frac{1}{x^2} y(x)\bigg) = x^2$$

An ideas?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Is my edit correct?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: The LHS of the last equation should be $ \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{y}{x^2} )$ ?

Comment: @projectilemotion ... You have sorted it in your answer ... Can you edit the question ? ... or did Fallet originally write that ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is your mistake:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{2}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{x^2} \cdot y = \frac{1}{x^2} \cdot x^2 $$

This leads to:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{x^2} \cdot y(x)\right) = \color{red}{1}$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: I went there but then I got 0 due to the derivative. Or shouldn't I derive the right side of the equation?

Comment: No, don't differentiate the right side of the equation. Integrate both sides with respect to $x$:
$$\int \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot y(x)\right)~dx=\int 1~dx$$
$$\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot y(x)=\int 1~dx$$

Comment: Oh now I get it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

An integrating factor of
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}-\frac{2y}x=x^2$$
is $\mu(x)=\exp\left[\int-\frac2xdx\right]=x^{-2}$. So, by multiplying both sides of the preceding equation by $\mu(x)=x^{-2}$ we get
\begin{align*}
x^{-2}\frac{dy}{dx}-2x^{-3}y&=1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

A very systematic and general but maybe **over-course** approach is to first rewrite your last equation to:

$$y\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = x^4$$

**EDIT** will work also with projectilemotion's fix, just replace $x^4$ with $x^2$.

In terms of a power series expansion, the left hand side is almost an autoconvolution and the right hand side provides a very simple objective $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kx^k, c_k= \cases{1, k=4 (or 2)\\0, k\neq 4 (or 2)}$$

If we solve systematically from the end: $$c_1c_0=0\\c_0\frac{c_2}{2}+c_1^2=0 \\\vdots$$

The right hand sides being the $c_k$ in the sum above. We will now be able do narrow down the $c_k$ from low $k$ and increasing.